# Control of colors in complex network graph using igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to change the colors on a graph I created of a network. Below is sample code.

```
require(igraph)
set.seed(0)
edges<-as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,1,2,2,3,5,8,8),c(2,3,4,8,4,7,6,7)))
names(edges)<-c("x","y")
g = graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = FALSE)
cfg<-cluster_optimal(g)
plot(cfg,g)
```

I like what the plot function is outputting, but I'd like to be able to control the colors, specifically of the cluster highlights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the clusters highlight:

```
plot(cfg,g, mark.col=c("red","green"))
```

[image]